# Preventing a setState from running until network request is complete

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function, inside of a Context file in my React app:

```
const fetchAll = (userId) => {

        try {
            fetchDetails(userId)
            // To be clear... There's multiple functions here, i.e:
            // fetchContact(userId)

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } 

        setPending(false)

    }
```

I've removed some of the functions - but the main premise of the function is to combine multiple promises together, and until these are complete, display a 'pending' component.

This pending component is displayed if the 'pending' state is set to true:

```
const [pending, setPending] = useState(true)
```

However, at the moment, what is happening is that the try is attempted, but the setPending is executed at the same time.

I thought one way around this would be to utilise a 'finally' call at the end of the my try / catch, but that still executes at the same time. Like this:

```
const fetchAll = (userId) => {

        try {
            fetchDetails(userId)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } finally {
            setPending(false)
        }

    }
```

I don't want any of my functions to be run asynchronously: I want them all to execute at the same time to prevent a waterfall effect of multiple network requests at once.

For reference, my individual 'fetch' functions call an endpoint and set state data based upon the response:

```
const fetchDetails = (userId) => {
        axios.post("/api/fetch/fetchDetails", {
            id: userId
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            setName(response.data.name)
            setPreviewPhoto(response.data.profile_picture_url)
            setPhotoName(response.data.profile_picture_name)
            setPhotoFile(response.data.profile_picture_url)
        })
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have 2 API calls: fetchAll('123') and fetchAll('321');

In order to wait for all of your requests and then update your state, you should use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) like this:

```js
Promise.all([fetchAll('123'), fetchAll('321')]).then((responses) => {
  setPending(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetchDetails` returning a promise, you need to use async/await

```
const fetchAll = async (userId) => {

    try {
        await fetchDetails(userId)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } finally {
        setPending(false)
    }

}
```

Comment: Nope, this is wrong. Like I said, I don't want to create a waterfall effect with my functions. I have multiple functions executing in my try, so they all need to run at once.

Comment: No . Axio call is asynchronous. you need to wait till it's resolved otherwise javascript tread will continue the execution before resolving the promise

Comment: using Promise.all can solve it to some extent, but it will be better, if it is possible to fetch all data from the server in one call

Comment: if there are multiple API calls then promise all is suitable. But since only one API call is here, don't need to use all

Comment: I said in the question there were multiple API calls :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple async calls using `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()` depending on your use case.

```
setPending(true)
try {
  await Promise.all([() => fetchAll(1), () => fetchAll(2)])
} finally {
  setPending(false)
}
```

This will wait for all calls to complete (or one to fail)